# Plotting image in the top of figure matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I found this script for plotting images:

import matplotlib.image as image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
im = image.imread('test.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im, aspect='auto', extent=(0.1, 0.5, .3, .6), zorder=-1)
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black', labelsize=15)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#D3D3D3', linestyle='-')
ax.scatter([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1], alpha=1.0)
plt.show()
```

I was wondering how I could tweak this script in order to place the image test.png in the top left corner of the figure?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the `extent` values in `imshow`?

Comment: Use e.g. `extent=(4,5,4,5)` to place the figure in the upper right corner. Are you looking for a general solution or for a solution for this specific case?